# Move values around in the code

Tags: c#, string, text

I want to take a value from let's say a textbox and then move it let's say a Click event to somewhere else in the code. So this is what I did:

First I made a private string like this:

```
private string someText;
```

Then I have the following code in my Click event:

```
someText = inputText.Text;
```

And now I want to use this on another place, so I thought that I could just use it like this:

```
TextBlock1.Text = someText;
```

But the string `someText` is empty here. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is this all in the same class? Are you sure the click event is being triggered before the TextBlock1.Text is set?

Comment: is this in asp.net or windowforms?

Comment: Check with the debugger how the value of `someText` changes. You can also use `Trace` or `Debug` classes or a proper logger to help you with that. In theory, you should be able to do that, watch that you use exactly the same instance and that no one else changes the value.

Comment: debug into the click event

Comment: Its all in the same class and the click event is triggered before the textblock1 is set. When debbugging in clickevent it has the value from the inputText.Text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow this method of a private string or public string didnt work.
So i solved it by saving it as isolatedstorage and cleard it when used.

Maybe a dumb solution to it but i worked.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on when you are assigning your TextBlock1.Text, since you onClick-event fires after the pageload.

It would help if you could give an example of where/when you are assigning/drawing on your someText.

(And what context you're working in, a website, WPF app or the like :))

Comment: From your comments to Nolonar's answer, you are trying to use the value in differing events. You should be aware that your someText will be cleared when you trigger another event needing a postback.

Comment: I misclicked enter halfway through my earlier comment - As a workaround you could store your someText in a Session variable (f.i.) and use that in your second event (Which I assume is triggered after your first?)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it in the same class it should work, if you are trying to use it outside the class you will need to expose it for example by declaring it as public or creating a public property for it.

Answer (score 0):

try to change :

`private string someText;` to be `public string someText;`

and initialize

`inputText` as `public TextBox inputText;`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you make "private string someText" local variable.

You should make global variable

for example

```
 class A
  {
      private string someText; //here 

      //Your Event
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are likely doing this:

```
private string someText;
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    TextBlock1.Text = someText; // At this point, someText == null
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    someText = inputText.Text;
}
```

So what you actually want, is this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    someText = inputText.Text;
    TextBlock1.Text = someText;

    // or simply
    TextBlock1.Text = inputText.Text;
    // for short
}
```

Comment: almost. What i want is to do in you example but with the difference that the TextBlock1.Text = someText is not in the same event.

Comment: Why can't it be in the same event?

Comment: Because i need to use the value later in another event. If i have a value in "inputText" and fire button_click i want to move this "inputText" value from the click_event to another. I cant set that in the other event TextBlock1.Text = InputText because its nothing there.